# Making MS Access report tied to SP lists available to SP users

Tags: 2010, reports, microsoft-access

This is SP2010 Server. Got a site with a number of lists. The primary list is a calendar, with a number of related lists tied to it. Using "Open With Access" in the Ribbon, I was able to create a number of Reports (as in MS Access report) that are just what the client wants.

But, this is in MS Access. The actual .accdb file is on my workstation. Doesn't help the client.

**Is there a way to somehow save that .accdb file back intoto SharePoint and expose the reports so that it would be possible to view them via something in the QuickLaunch, or otherwise have a URL that would open the reports?**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to publish that database to the Sharepoint server via Access Services. It would then reside in Sharepoint and the database and reports would be accessible. It might not be that simple though, Access Services is one of the features I haven't really touched.